# Automatically passing html attributes to svelte components

Tags: svelte

Is it not possible to allow svelte components to automatically apply all regular html attributes to the top most element within the component?

Component.html

```
<div>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Application.html

```
<div>
  <Component class="extend">
    Some text
  </Component>
</div>
```

And have the .extend added to the div inside the Component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can have multiple top level items in a component, this would not be possible. However you could do something similar to what I have outlined in this blog post for Ractive. You would have to make sure you are setting only 1 top level item per component though.

https://www.donielsmith.com/blog/2016/06/05/passing-attributes-down-with-ractivejs/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That could be an okay solution. Would it work with server side rendering, or would the hook only get called on the client, and would find("element") work on the server?

Comment: Just saw this https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/148 and hooks are not called on the server. So this would not work with serverside rendering. Unless there is some other way of hooking into the creation of the dom node this doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: This would still display an error as prop is not declared tho ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<Widget {...$$props}/>
<input {...$$restProps}>
```

It's possible but not recommended. Straight from the docs: https://svelte.dev/docs

> `$$props` References all props that are passed to a component, including ones
> that are not declared with export. It is not generally recommended, as
> it is difficult for Svelte to optimise. But it can be useful in rare
> cases – for example, when you don't know at compile time what props
> might be passed to a component.